# Zendframework link problem

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am very to new to zend frame work , I am trying to set up a project (Done by other programmer) in my local server, but in this project the all links to another are not working?

Plss help me!!!!!!!!1

Comment: Please read the faq on how to ask a question. There is not enough information provided for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where exactly relies your problem but it could be several things

- make sure the rewriting is working
  properly (Apache settings, IIS
  settings, .htaccess). You  check that
  by adding a `die('I am in
  index.php');` in your index file and
  browse some urls
- `$frontController->setBaseUrl` if your website is not at the root of the server your should set the baseurl to match that.

That's the two main reason that come to my mind now I would be glad to help more if you give more details...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Since I had a problem that is a bit like this. You may need to set up your virtual host for this one. Maybe the old developer used a certain virtual host. That is why it is not working when you transfered it to your local machine

Answer (score 0):

Check your VirtualHost settings, then check .htaccess or post this files.